# Check access to a page

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to create a method for checking if data access equals to next.data.access.
I can's use includes method because it's an array.
just one of the data access value in array is good to return true

auth.guards.ts

```
 canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return from(this.authService.me().then(data => {
      let access = data['role']['unlocks'];
      if('access' in next.data) {
        let eachAccess = next.data.access.forEach(each => {
          each.includes(access);
        } );
        let hasAccess = eachAccess === next.data.access;
        console.log(hasAccess)
        if (hasAccess) {
          return next.component !== LoginComponent;
        } else {
          console.warn('User doesn\'t have access to this page.');
          this.router.navigate(['/selection']);
          return false;
        }
```

routing module.ts

```
  { path: 'admin', canActivate:[AuthGuard], component: AdminComponent, data: {access : ['ALL']}, children: [
      { path: 'manageUsers', component: ManageUserComponent}
    ]},

  { path: 'client', canActivate:[AuthGuard], data: {access : ['ALL','CLIENT']}, children: [
      { path: '', component: DashboardComponent },
      { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
      { path: 'greenhouse', component: GreenhouseComponent},
      { path: 'recipe', component: RecipeComponent},
      { path: 'greenhouse/mylamps', component: MylampsComponent},
    ]},

  { path: 'tools', canActivate:[AuthGuard], data: {access : ['ALL','TOOLS']}, children: [
    { path: '', component: ToolsComponent },
    { path: 'information', component: UserInformationComponent},
    { path: 'light', component: LightComponent},
    { path: 'spectrum', component: RefSpectrumComponent},
    { path: 'test', component: TestComponent},
    { path: 'progress', component: InProgressComponent}
  ]},
```

Answer (score 0):

For such purpose, you can't use `forEach` as it will not return anything.

```js
const arr = arr = [1, 2, 3];
const res = arr.forEach(v => v *2);

console.log(res); // undefined
```

You can use instead [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
const hasAccess = next.data.access.includes(access);
```

Or, if you want to search for something more complex, you can use [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
const hasAccess = next.data.access.includes(acc => acc === access);
```

Comment: the condition hasAccess returns me false every time. The Api returns me ['ALL'] for data['role']['unlocks']. I just need to have condition to pass

Comment: I think I need to iterate on next.data.access and check if one return true.